# Is it possible to expand a tooltip expression in Moqui?

Tags: tooltip, moqui

Is this possible?

For example:

```
<default-field tooltip="${longDescription}" >
```

Coded as above, it just prints directly to screen ${longDescription} as the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last release only certain tooltip attributes were expanded (in the screen rendering FTL macros). The latest macros now expand the tooltip for all form field widgets (in commit #c994ae3).